# Symfony 4 + Doctrine DBAL cache driver

Tags: symfony, caching, dbal

I've started a really simple project, with just symfony/skeleton and doctrine/doctrine-bundle.

I'm NOT using ORM, just plain DBAL. Didn't install symfony/orm-pack.

I'm trying to cache the result of a simple query, and I'm getting exception with message "Trying to cache a query but no result driver is configured".

Example code:

```
$query = $connection->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('common.Language')
    ->getSQL();
$qcp = new QueryCacheProfile(0, "languages");
$stmt = $connection->executeCacheQuery($query, [], [], $qcp);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

I've read I could enable cache by implementing a small bundle to modify DBAL connection configuration on container compile phase [here](http://www.symfony-grenoble.fr/en/376/how-to-use-doctrine-dbal-cache-with-symfony2/).
But I can't get it to work. I guess because it tries to assign to DBAL same cache driver ORM is using, but I don't have ORM installed.

How should I do that? I've created a simple class which injects DBAL connection and configures cache at runtime, then all my repositories/daos inject that class. But I don't feel it to be the correct way to achieve that...

```
public function __construct(Connection $connection, ContainerInterface $container)
{
    /** @var Kernel $kernel */
    $kernel = $container->get('kernel');

    $cacheProviders = [];

    if ($kernel->isDebug()) {
        $cacheProviders[] = new ArrayCache();
    } else {
        $cacheProviders[] = new PhpFileCache($kernel->getCacheDir().'/dbal');
    }

    $connection->getConfiguration()->setResultCacheImpl(new ChainCache($cacheProviders));
}
```

PD: Using symfony 4.1 with DBAL 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

according to your post https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/833

and referencing that still opened https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/114  so  this feature is not solved!

for temp solving problem, i advice to you replace `executeCacheQuery` to  `executeQuery` +test:

```
    $qcp = new QueryCacheProfile('3600', "someKey");
    $qcp = empty($qcp->getResultCacheDriver()) ? null : $qcp;//test for existing 


    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
        $query,
        [],
        [],
        $qcp
```

after reading [DOCs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.5/reference/caching.html), noticed that config not set **UPDATED:**

```
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
    $config = $conn->getConfiguration();
    $config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);

    $qcp = new QueryCacheProfile('3600', "someKey", $cache);
    $qcp = empty($qcp->getResultCacheDriver()) ? null : $qcp;//cache driver exist?

    $stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
        $query,
        [],
        [],
        $qcp
    );
```